# Merge two dataframes in Pandas by taking the mean between the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes:

**df1**

```
          C1    C2     C3
    0     0     0      0
    1     0     0      0
```

**df2**

```
          C1    C4     C5
    0     1     1      1
    1     1     1      1
```

The result I am looking for is:

**df3**

```
          C1    C2     C3    C4    C5
    0     0.5    0      0     1     1
    1     0.5    0      0     1     1
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `DataFrame.add`

```
df3 = df2.add(df1, fill_value=0)
df3[df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)] /= 2

    C1   C2   C3   C4   C5
0  0.5  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
1  0.5  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
```

---

## `concat` + `groupby`

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).groupby(axis=1, level=0).mean()
    C1   C2   C3   C4   C5
0  0.5  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
1  0.5  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can using `concat` and `groupby` axis =1

```
s=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
s.groupby(s.columns.values,axis=1).mean()
Out[116]: 
    C1   C2   C3   C4   C5
0  0.5  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
1  0.5  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
```

A nice alternative from  @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

```
s.groupby(level=0,axis=1).mean()
Out[117]: 
    C1   C2   C3   C4   C5
0  0.5  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
1  0.5  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Try `level=0` instead of `s.columns.values`

Comment: You're welcome. I found an alternative method as well, thought you may be interested.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yep that is great , I do upvoted before you deleted :-) ha